# Gitlab - Transfer to other namespace not working

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-7, gitlab-omnibus

I moved a git-repository to another namespace in gitlab through the 'transfer project' option in the Admin Area. I am owner/master of both namespaces.

The first time I did the transfer it took ages for the page to automatically refresh after the move; but I figured I just let it run it's course; when I clicked away to another page and then got back, nothing seemed to have happened: Project was still in the old namespace, project is not visible in the new namespace.

However in the old namespace, it now says: " repository: does not exist" in the Project info and if I go look on disk, the nameofrepository.git & nameofrepository.wiki.git are actually moved into the directory of the new namespace and are not in the old directory anymore.

Is there any way of updating/fixing this information in gitlab easily? I did restart gitlab already, but that didn't seem to help out at all.

We're running gitlab 7.5.1

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this?  I transferred a project to a new namespace in GitLab, updated my Eclipse stuff but GitLab CI still shows the old namespace.  Any click to "View On GitLab" results in a 404.

Comment: I'm sorry, I honestly can't remember what I did to fix this; I know the problem got solved eventually, but I also remember it to be a user-error.
I think I asked around on irc for help with this issue, I'll search my irssi-logs and let you know!

Comment: Nope, sorry, can't find any trace of this problem anymore except for frantic searches on google ;)
I do know that we upgraded our gitlab instance to the latest version shortly after this problem occured, it might've been fixed with that upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem in GitLab 7.1.1.  The move made the original repo empty but the project did not appear in the destination group.  We fixed it as follows (for this purpose let's say the original project x was in group a, and it was being moved to group b):

- Browse to the repositories folder on the GitLab server.
- Locate the target group b and folder x (which is what we found). This meant GitLab had moved the folder but not created the project correctly.
- In GitLab create a new project in group b called temp.
- Rename the project folder x in group b to temp.
- Check in GitLab that the project contents is now available in group b, project temp.
- If all is well, in GitLab rename project temp to whatever you want it to be (probably project x).

If those instructions are a bit convoluted, the main point is getting GitLab to create a project and then overwrite the projects folder with the moved folder.  Why the project does not appear I don't know, but presume it's a bug with GitLab.